# Can't create two Types to same index elasticsearch & Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new in elasticsearch and kibana

I'm doing some exercices with elasticsearch (create index,types and documents..)

I created an index 'business' with type 'building'

```
put /business/building/217
{
  "adresse":"11 Pen Ave",
  "floors":5,
  "offices":7,
  "loc":{
    "lat":40.693479,
    "lon":-73.983854
  }
}
```

it works funny but when I tried to create another type like this

```
put /business/employee/330
{
  "name":"Richard Bell",
  "title":"Senior Accountant",
  "salar_usd":115000.00,
  "hiredate":"Jan 19, 2013"
}
```

then I got this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [business] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [employee, building]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [business] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [employee, building]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 46):

You're probably running Elasticsearch version 6 and as of that version ES doesn't allow you to create [more than one type](https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch) in any given index.

You need to store each of your document type inside a dedicated index, e.g.

```
PUT /business/building/217
{
  "adresse":"11 Pen Ave",
  "floors":5,
  "offices":7,
  "loc":{
    "lat":40.693479,
    "lon":-73.983854
  }
}

PUT /employees/employee/330
{
  "name":"Richard Bell",
  "title":"Senior Accountant",
  "salar_usd":115000.00,
  "hiredate":"Jan 19, 2013"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/removal-of-types.html for more.

> **Elasticsearch 6.x**
>   Indices created in 6.x only allow a single-type per index. Any name can be used for the type, but there can be only one. The preferred type name is _doc, so that index APIs have the same path as they will have in 7.0: PUT {index}/_doc/{id} and POST {index}/_doc