# Elasticsearch 6: Rejecting mapping update as the final mapping would have more than 1 type

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to convert a project to use the latest Elasticsearch 6 and am having this problem. I don't know if the problem is "Product" vs "product". In my mappings and attributes I specify "products", so I am not sure why I get this error when I try to index a product.

Error:

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on PUT:
>   /products/products/1?pretty=true&error_trace=true
>
> "Rejecting mapping update to [products] as the final mapping would
>   have more than 1 type: [Product, products]"

Request:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "warehouseId": 0,
  "productStatus": 1,
  "sku": "102377",
  "name": "Name",
  "shortDescription": "Description",
  "longDescription": "Description",
  "price": 37.3200
}
```

My code:

```
    [ElasticsearchType(Name = "products")]
    public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int WarehouseId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Product Status")]
        public Enums.ProductStatus ProductStatus { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(10)]
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Short Description")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText), Display(Name = "Long Description")]
        public string LongDescription { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName ="Money")]            
        public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    }

connection.DefaultMappingFor<Product>(m => m.IndexName("products"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create two Types to same index elasticsearch & Kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632846/cant-create-two-types-to-same-index-elasticsearch-kibana)

Answer (score 29):

This is because of a breaking change in ES 6.x: [mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping.html#mapping-type) were removed (even if for backward compatibility you can still specify it in the path) thus de facto limiting the index to a single type.

[See here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html) for more info.

Comment: I am trying to migrate from ES 5 to 7, and it confuses me that some say mappings are removed, since they still talk about mappings in the docs for version 7: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/mapping.html

Comment: **mapping types** were removed. Before ES6 you could define more than one mapping type in the same index (say, `user` and `order`). Starting from ES6, indexes were constrained to a single mapping (so we still have a _mapping_), making the concept of _type_ redundant.

See the doc [removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/removal-of-types.html) for the reason behind this update

Comment: Thanks Cavaz... It confused me that you wrote "mappings were removed"... I guess it should have been "mapping types were removed".

Answer (score 6):

Prior to elasticsearch v6, an index can have only 1 mapping by default. In previous version 5.x, multiple mapping was possible for an index. Though you may change this default setting by updating index setting `"index.mapping.single_type": false` .

In your case, my assumption is you had already created the index with mapping `Product`. That is why it was rejecting new mapping in your second request with "product" (p in small case).

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the index and recreated it and it appears to be fine now. I think when I first created the index I didn't have the correct attribute name so that might explain the error I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to delete a record following the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html) and I blindly put the `_doc` in the URL which led to this error.

This should be the mapping that you see under the `Indices` tab against `Mappings` section in the AWS console. changing the value in the URL solved it for me.

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

As Batsu says, from version 5 of elasticSearch onwards, the concept of treating the index as the database and the type as a table was removed to implement a lucene optimization.

The solution is to use an index by @Document.

Referral: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/removal-of-types.html

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in ES 6.8 for which I was using the PHP ElasticSearch client to send requests. My index was already using a single `type` but the type name was not the default `_doc` that was suggested/expected. In addition I was not adding the "type" parameter in the request to specify what the type was. My code:

```
$this->client->delete([
   "index" => 'myIndexName',
   "id" => $idToDelete
])
```

This resulted in the client adding a default type which was `_doc` which in my case was incorrect. Adding an explicit type in the request fixed the issue like below:

```
$this->client->delete([
   "index" => 'myIndexName',
   'type' => 'myTypeName',
   "id" => $idToDelete
])
```

Answer (score 0):

As there would be a type for index ,
use below method to create mapping so that it maps with its type

```
client.indices.putMapping({
                index: indexName,
                include_type_name:true,
                type: type,
                body: mappingBody,
            })
            .then(async function (response: any) {
                console.log('response', response);
                return response;
            })
            .catch(function (error: any) {
                console.log('error', error);
                throw error;
            });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).