# Elasticsearch 6 rejecting mapping update to even on simple document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

After upgrading from ES 5 to ES 6 I've got error message each time i want to store something in new index. However all old indexes are working fine.

The error message is:

> Rejecting mapping update to [test] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [user, group]

Im using elasticsearch 6.3. It works properly on production server on previously created indexes. I've tried dropping index to no avail.

My test documents are:

```
PUT test/group/1
{
    "id": "5b29fb9aa3d24b5a2b6b8fcb",
    "_mongo_id_": "5b29fb9aa3d24b5a2b6b8fcb"
}
```

and

```
PUT test/user/1
{
  "id": "5ad4800ca3d24be81d7a6806",
  "_mongo_id_": "5ad4800ca3d24be81d7a6806"
}
```

Index mapping seems ok:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "group": {
      "properties": {
        "_mongo_id_": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create two Types to same index elasticsearch & Kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632846/cant-create-two-types-to-same-index-elasticsearch-kibana)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add more than one `type` per `index`

PUT test/`group`/1

PUT test/`user`/1

This behaviour is not allowed from ES 6.

From [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/breaking-changes-6.0.html)

> The ability to have multiple mapping types per index has been removed
>   in 6.0. New indices will be restricted to a single type. This is the
>   first step in the plan to remove mapping types altogether. Indices
>   created in 5.x will continue to support multiple mapping types.

Comment: So now I understand why it worked until I re-created index. The elasticsearch is so elastic that it's hard to hold it!